# C# - Best way to continuously check a process

Tags: c#, netsuite

Scenario: A Azure WebJob that will get all the Vendor record from NetSuite via WSDL.

Problem: The dataset is too large. Even with service set to 12 minutes time out. It still time out and the code failed.

NetSuite have a async process that basically run whatever you want on the server and it will return a JobId that allowed you to check the process on the server.

What I did currently is by making a search call first asking for all the Vendor records and it is to be process on the server. After I got the JobId, i wrote a void Recursion that check if the job is finish on the server with Thread Sleep set to 10 minutes.

```
 private static bool ChkProcess(VendorsService vendorService, string jobId)
    {
        var isJobDone = false;

        //Recursion 
        void ChkAsyncProgress(bool isFinish)
        {
            if (isFinish) return;

            var chkJobProgress = vendorService.NsCheckProcessStatus(jobId);
            if (chkJobProgress.OperationResult.IsFinish) isJobDone = true;

            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
            ChkAsyncProgress(isJobDone);
        }

        ChkAsyncProgress(false);
        return isJobDone;
    }
```

It work but is there a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: What about async APIs and `IProgress` implementation, this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) shows some examples

Answer (score 0):

I think that since you're working with Azure already, with [Service BUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus/) you can implement a really low cost solution for this (if not free, depending on how much frequent is your job running)

Basically it's a queue where you enqueue messages (which can be objects with properties too, so they could also contain your result of the elaboration potentially).

A service bus is used to enqueue.
An azure function of type ServiceBusTrigger listens automatically if any new message on service bus has arrived and gets triggered if so (or, you can set messages to be enqueued, but be available after a certain future time only).

So, in the webjob code, at the end you could add code to enqueue a message which will mark the webjob has finished elaboration.

The azure function will get immediately noticed as soon as the message gets in the queue and you can retrieve the data without polling constantly for job completion, as azure will take care of all of that for you for a ridiculous price and without any effort by you.

Also, these task aren't priced timely based, but execution based, so you will pay only when it effectively put a message in queue.

They have a certain number of executions free, so it might be that you don't even need to pay anything.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) some microsoft code sample for doing so.